# python3: pandas' to_json is adding \ to each double quote in one of my key values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a json made from twitter scraping. Some of the tweets have backslashes preceding a quote being used. This is only seen within the tweet message and not the keys of my json.
I have the below code which will remove a lot of rubbish including the back slash but the newly saved json still has the back slashed

I recently found that the problem wasn't the regex, but with the to_json. pandas is removing the back slashes through regex and then reapplying the back slash when i use to_json. Is there some way I resolve this? my goal is to read a json in its original format, remove unnecessary clutter, then resave it to a new json in the exact same format it came in

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(filename, orient=columnName,encoding="utf-8"),columns=columnName)
data['full_text'] = data['full_text'].replace('^@ABC(\\u2019s)*[ ,\n]*', '', regex=True)
data['full_text'] = data['full_text'].replace('(\\u2019)', "'", regex=True)
data['full_text'] = data['full_text'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\\(?=\")','"',x))
print(data['full_text'].loc[data['id_str'] == 79104606646138400])
data.to_json('new_abc_short.json',orient='records')
```

example key value pair straight from new json (opened in notepad++):

```
....,"full_text":"How can you \"accidentally close\" my account",....
```

what i expected:

```
....,"full_text":"How can you "accidentally close" my account",....
```

not every double quote has the issue, like in the key full_text, the part I'm worried about is the value of it. it it matters, i noticed from the print that full_text is of dtype object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"full_text":"How can you "accidentally close" my account"` is not valid JSON.  The `\` are there to escape the quotes inside the string, telling the parser that these quotes should be included with the string rather than determine the JSON structure.  When you read that JSON back into another application, a reasonable JSON parser will remove the quotes for you.

Comment: aw :( ok then, i guess that's fine